# Get Sending Control's Name property to be used in opacity change

Tags: c#, binding, casting, opacity, graphic

Ok I'll try explain as best as possible.

I have a method, "HandleGraphic". This method will be..Handling the opacity of a given control via a Logarithmic function.

The method parameters are: (object SendingObject, float From, float To)

My question is: How do I cast/bind the SendingObject in such a way as to directly be able to manipulate it's values/properties?

For instance: Say the textbox calls the HandleGraphic method. The HandleGraphic needs the sending control's Name property "txtbox" to adjust it's Opacity property.

There must be a way of implementing a global function of casting or binding to directly access the calling object's property.

For instance: `SendingObject.Opacity = X;`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about WPF (WinForms controls don't have an Opacity property), both the Name and Opacity properties are members of `Control` (specifically `System.Windows.Controls.Control`). Why not change the signature of HandleGraphic to (Control control, float from, float to)? All controls derive from Control, so you can pass any of them to that method.

**Correction**

The `Name` property is a member of `FrameworkElement` and the `Opacity` property is a member of `UIElement`. So to work with both Name and Opacity property you need at minimum a `FrameworkElement`. `Control` will still work for your purpose, but you might want to aim for the lowest common denominator. For example, a `TextBlock` is not a `Control`, it derives directly from `FrameworkElement`.

The hierarchy of controls in WPF is:

```
Object
DispatcherObject
DependencyObject
Visual
UIElement
FrameworkElement
Control
```

From there it gets complicated. For instance:

```
Button : ButtonBase : ContentControl : Control
TextBox : TextBoxBase : Control
ComboBox : Selector : ItemsControl : Control
DataGrid : MultiSelector : Selector : ItemsControl : Control
```

But they all derive from `Control` which derives from `FrameworkElement`.

The simplest way to find out the inheritance of a type is to put the caret on the type in your code and press F12. This gives you some pseudo-code describing the type (or actual code if it's available) and you can navigate through the base classes the same way.